# assign elements from a list of list to a dictionary

Tags: python

i have this code:

```
list1 = [['player1', 5,1,300,100, ..., n],['player2', 10,5,650,150,...n],['player3', 17,6,1100,1050...,n]]

dictionary  = {
    'playersname':[]
    'totalwin':[]
    'totalloss':[]
    'moneywon':[]
    'moneyloss':[]
    }

for x in listplayers:
    dictionary['name'].append(x[0])
    dictionary['totalwins'].append(x[1])
    dictionary['totalloss'].append(x[2])
    dictionary['moneywon'].append(x[3])
    dictionary['moneylost'].append(x[4])
```

my output:

```
dictionary = {
    'name': [player1,player2,player3,...,n], 
    'totalwin':[5,10,17,...,n],
    'totalloss':[1,5,6],
    'moneywon':[300,650,1100],
    'moneyloss':[100,150,1050], 
    }
```

it works just fine, but i have to write out every dictionary keys and append every items individually
(ex:dictionary['totalwins'].append(x[1]))
so if i had a dictionary with 30 keys and a list with 30 different players caracteristics(ex:win, lost, etc) i would have to write 30 lines.

Is there a way to write the same code in fewer lines (ex:loop through everything) instead of writing 30 lines like so:

```
1    for x in listplayers:
2        dictionary['name'].append(x[0])
3        dictionary['totalwins'].append(x[1])
...      ...
30       dictionary['key30'].append(x[30])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a list of keys, you can `zip` up the values, then `zip` that up with the key passing the whole thing to `dict()`

```
listplayers = [['player1',5,1,300,100], ['player2',10,5,650,150], ['player3',17,6,1100,1050]]
keys = ['playersname','totalwins','totalloss','moneywon','moneylost']

dictionary = dict(zip(keys, zip(*listplayers)))

dictionary

# {'playersname': ('player1', 'player2', 'player3'),
#  'totalwins': (5, 10, 17),
#  'totalloss': (1, 5, 6),
#  'moneywon': (300, 650, 1100),
#  'moneylost': (100, 150, 1050)}
```

Notice, this give you tuples, not lists. If that's a problem, you can wrap the zips in a dict comprehension or use `map` to convert them:

```
dictionary = {key: list(values) for key, values in zip(keys, zip(*listplayers))}
```

or

```
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, map(list,zip(*listplayers))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following.

```
list1 = [['player1', 5,1,300,100],['player2', 10,5,650,150]]
dictionary = {f'key_{i}':[*x] for i,x in enumerate(zip(*list1))}
```

The resulting dictionary:

```
{'key_0': ['player1', 'player2'],
 'key_1': [5, 10],
 'key_2': [1, 5],
 'key_3': [300, 650],
 'key_4': [100, 150]}
```

Or, if you have some key names in mind:

```
list1 = [['player1', 5,1,300,100],['player2', 10,5,650,150]]
keys = ['playersname',
    'totalwin',
    'totalloss',
    'moneywon',
    'moneyloss']

{keys[i]:[*x] for i,x in enumerate(zip(*list1))}
```

The result:

```
{'playersname': ['player1', 'player2'],
 'totalwin': [5, 10],
 'totalloss': [1, 5],
 'moneywon': [300, 650],
 'moneyloss': [100, 150]}
```